# Jenkins paramaterized builds list file entries in a drop down menu

Tags: jenkins, build-process

I would like to list all files entries in a drop-down list through a parameterized build option in Jenkins. How can I achieve this?

Comment: File entries from where?

Answer (score 4):

You are a little vague on what "file entries" you want to list. If you just want to display a list of files from a directory, have a look at **[Extensible Choice Parameter](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Extensible+Choice+Parameter+plugin)** plugin. It has a mode for "File Choice Parameter" that allows you to do just that.

If you want list values *from* a file, then you would want **[Extended Choice Parameter](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Extended+Choice+Parameter+plugin)** plugin

Comment: thanks for reply Slav. I am looking for on eproperty file contents display in a drop down. This file will have version control tool branches list.

Comment: @Srinivas In that case, you want Extended choice Parameter plugin. I've edited the answer.

Comment: Thanks for referencing Extensible Choice Parameter plugin